# Adding a second addEventListener() breaks the first one

Tags: javascript

I'm hiding a p on load, then clicking the button should show it, clicking elsewhere after will hide it.

I can hide it and then show it on the button click, but when I add another addEventListener to hide it when clicking anywhere, it breaks it.

html:

```
<button id="btn">click me</button>

<p id="p">text here</p>
```

JS:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
var p = document.getElementById('p')

p.style.display = "none"

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  p.style.display = "block"

    document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    p.style.display = "none" 
  })

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v65qh4o1/

Comment: Every time you click the button you're adding another click handler on the `document`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are adding eventlistener on the document, so whenever you'll click on the button it will still trigger as the button is also a part of the document and when you click on button you indirectly clicked on the document.

try to do it this way.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
var p = document.getElementById('p')

p.style.display = "none"

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  p.style.display = "block"
})
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if(event.target !== btn){
    p.style.display = "none"    
  }

});
```

Check out the working [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gsymdrj3/6/)

---

**Update**

to prevent text to hide on click of `<p>` add another condition in the `if` statement.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if(event.target !== btn && event.target !== p){
    p.style.display = "none"    
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 Correct answer, minor adjustment here -> https://jsfiddle.net/3g60zoL9/ so you aren't having to query the document a second time for the ID and instead use the stored `btn` var.

Comment: thanks, this worked and I understand my problem now. But still I need it when you click on the p tag, nothing happens. Only hide it when clicking elsewhere, I've been trying this for an hour with no progress. : (

Comment: got it!! `if(event.target !== btn && event.target != p){` thanks again : )

Answer (score 0):

That's because event listeners *bubble up*, so if you click the button, the whole document also gets clicked. So when you click the button the first time, the listener gets attached to the document, then whenever you click it, both listeners get triggered undoing each others changes.

You could let the inner handler only be triggered once, to not pollute the event handlers list:

```
 btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  p.style.display = "block"

  document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    p.style.display = "none" 
  }, { once: true });
});
```

In case you don't want a second button click to not hide the paragraph again, you can prevent the event from bubbling with:

```
 btn.addEventListener(function (event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   //...
 });
```

Comment: _"the inner handler only be attached once"_: `once: true` does not prevent the script to add multiple click handlers on the document. It only "forces" the browser to remove the handler after it has been executed once/the first time.